# Pattern recognition in a square matrix

Tags: python

Imaging a grid of 10 x 10 squares.

Squares can be colored to form a continous (connected) path from one side to another, either vertically or horizontally. 
I am making a code that places colored squares and defines how they are connected. However, how do I make the code that recognizes if there is a path from side to side? It may have any form and contain an arbitrary number of colored squares (but at least ten) 
Any general ideas would be appreciated!:) 
[Orange squares placed in a matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sw9M.png)

Comment: Something similar to this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-possible-path-2d-matrix/) and adapt it for other start and end squares. You might wanna look into dynamic programming for this, as brute forcing it will take some time.